# Is there a way to read table data (parse) from pdf file using Adobe reader Type library

Tags: c#, asp.net, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I am working on C#.net project. I have a pdf file which contains some table structure data. I have google a lot how even not able to get the answer about how to read the table data from pdf file in C# code.

I tried iTextSharp, PdfBOX, pdfSharp etc. However not able to get it. Is there a way to read the data.

OR

Is it possible to read table data from pdf file using adobe reader type lib?

Have seen many question on stackoverflow, however not a perfact answer i got.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ivy PDF: www.ivytools.net

It can extract tabular data pretty well (assuming the tables have a proper structure).